# Android activity, service, notification and application launcher

Tags: android, android-activity, service, notifications

I need your help because I want to write an Android app which works like this: when I tap the app launcher, I show an activity in which the user has to insert some data, like his name ecc. These data are passed to a background service through an intent and when the service starts I show a notification. When I click on the notification I show another activity in which the user can press a button to stop the service. Everything works fine but I would like that, if I tap again the app launcher but the service is active, the user didn't see the first activity (the one in which he has to insert the data), but the last one in which there is the button to press to stop the service. I don't have a clue of how to do. Can you help me please? Thanks.

Comment: It's not possible to tell what's wrong without seeing the source code for your app. How do you start the service and activities? What's in your manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need two `Activities` for these use cases? You can have just one `Activity` and two `Fragments`, one for starting the `Service`, and one for stopping. In your `Activity's` `onCreate()` method check if the `Service` is running and inflate the right `Fragment` dynamically.

Comment: Could you please provide an example about it? Just a little one... I'm a bit confused...